# Construct a one to one function $f$ between $A$ and $A-B$, given $A$ is infinite and $B \subset A$ is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I think it is quite clear(?) that $A-B$ and $A$ have the same cardinality therefore a one-to-one correspondence should exist, but how do I construct such a function? I imagine that an identity function ($f(x)=x$) should be involved if $x\in A-B$, but how do I handle the case $x\in B$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Say $|B|=n$ and label $B = \{b_0,\ldots, b_{n-1}\}.$ Let $C$ be a countably infinite subset of $A-B$ and let $C_0,\ldots, C_{n-1}$ be a partition of $C$ into $n$ countably infinite subsets. Enumerate each as $C_i = \{c_{i,j}:j\in \mathbb N\}.$ Then define $f:A-B\to A$ by $f(x)=x$ for $x\notin C$, $f(c_{i,0}) = b_i,$ and $f(c_{i,j+1})= c_{i,j}.$

"Quite clear" is subjective. This proof is non-constructive in the sense that we had to use a countably infinite subset of the infinite set $A-B$ without an explicit construction of such a set, and in fact there is no way to prove this theorem without [(a very weak form of) the axiom of choice.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set)

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is infinite, you can find a numerable set $A'\subset A$ and, without loss of generality, you can assume that $B\subset A'$ (if not, take $A'':=A'\cup B$).

Now define $f$ as follows: $f(x)=x$ if $x\in A\setminus A'$.

Let $m:=card(B)$. Assume tha $A'=\{x_n:\, n\in\Bbb N\}$ such that $\{x_1,\cdots,x_m\}=B$.
Now define $f(x_n)=x_{n+m}$.